# ODBC connection takes a really long time to execute

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, ms-office

I have an Excel spreadsheet with ODBC connection which executes a query and populates the data in a tab. **Refresh All** takes a really long time (around 15 mins) to execute.

Most of the time is wasted on the status *Connecting to data source*.

My connection string looks something like this:

`Provider=SQLOLED;Password=XXXXXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Data Source=XXXXXXXXXX;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=XXXXX;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False`

I read online that Named Pipes (`np:`) may help, but I cannot use it as it throws an error saying it does not recognize the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know in case you need any more information.

Answer (score 1):

You've XXXX'ed out several parameters, which might play a role in the connection taking a long time to initiate.  For instance, you might find it goes faster if you target the server by IP address rather than by FQDN or Windows hostname.

I would also suggest checking that ODBC tracing is disabled, as this can massively slow down all ODBC operations.

Also, I note `Provider=SQLOLED` in your connect string. This is the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server -- not an ODBC Driver! -- so it is quite unlikely that the above is actually the connect string in use, as Excel is an ODBC client, not an OLE DB client, application.